# TensorFlow 2.0 How to get trainable variables from tf.keras.layers layers, like Conv2D or Dense

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have been trying to get the trainable variables from my layers and can't figure out a way to make it work. So here is what I have tried:

I have tried accessing the kernel and bias attribute of the Dense or Conv2D object directly, but to no avail. The type of result that I get is "Dense object has no attribute 'kernel'".

```
trainable_variables.append(conv_layer.kernel)
trainable_variables.append(conv_layer.bias)
```

Similarly, I have tried using the attribute "trainable_variables" in the following way:

```
trainable_variables.extend(conv_layer.trainable_variables)
```

From what I know this is supposed to return a list of two variables, the weight and the bias variables. However, what I get is an empty list.

Any idea of how to get the variables from labels in TensorFlow 2.0? I want to be able to later feed those variables to an optimizer, in a way similar to the following:

```
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_variables))
```

Edit:
Here is part of my current code to serve as an example and help answering the question (Hope it is readable)

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, Reshape, Flatten

... 

class Network:
    def __init__(self, params):
        weights_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=params["seed"])
        bias_initializer = tf.initializers.Constant(0.0)

        self.trainable_variables = []

        self.conv_layers = []
        self.conv_activations = []
        self.create_conv_layers(params, weights_initializer, bias_initializer)

        self.flatten_layer = Flatten()


        self.dense_layers = []
        self.dense_activations = []
        self.create_dense_layers(params, weights_initializer, bias_initializer)

        self.output_layer = Dense(1, kernel_initializer=weights_initializer, bias_initializer=bias_initializer)
        self.trainable_variables.append(self.output_layer.kernel)
        self.trainable_variables.append(self.output_layer.bias)

    def create_conv_layers(self, params, weight_init, bias_init):
        nconv = len(params['stride'])
        for i in range(nconv):
            conv_layer = Conv2D(filters=params["nfilter"][i],
                                kernel_size=params["shape"][i], kernel_initializer=weight_init,
                                kernel_regularizer=spectral_norm,
                                use_bias=True, bias_initializer=bias_init,
                                strides=params["stride"][i],
                                padding="same", )
            self.conv_layers.append(conv_layer)
            self.trainable_variables.append(conv_layer.kernel)
            self.trainable_variables.append(conv_layer.bias)
            self.conv_activations.append(params["activation"])

    def create_conv_layers(self, params, weight_init, bias_init):
        nconv = len(params['stride'])
        for i in range(nconv):
            conv_layer = Conv2D(filters=params["nfilter"][i],
                                kernel_size=params["shape"][i], kernel_initializer=weight_init,
                                kernel_regularizer=spectral_norm,
                                use_bias=True, bias_initializer=bias_init,
                                strides=params["stride"][i],
                                padding="same", )
            self.conv_layers.append(conv_layer)
            self.trainable_variables.append(conv_layer.kernel)
            self.trainable_variables.append(conv_layer.bias)
            self.conv_activations.append(params["activation"])
```

As you can see I am trying to gather all my trainable variables into a list attribute called trainable_variables. However as I mentioned this code does not work because I get an error for trying to acquire the kernel and bias attributes of those layer objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, so I think I found the problem.

The trainable variables were not available until I used the given layer object. After I run my forward pass I could retrieve attributes of the tf.keras.layers.Layer object like trainable_variables and weights.

However, before my forward pass I received an empty list. To make things a little bit more clear:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    print(dense_layers[0].trainable_variables)
    self.forward_pass(X)
    self.compute_loss()
    print(dense_layers[0].trainable_variables)
```

On the code above, the attribute trainable_variables is an empty list before executing self.forward_pass. However, right after it, I could retrieve the kernel and bias numpy arrays.

Comment: I think this is has to do with the tensorflow way of building graphs where it is initially empty.

Comment: the same here! i have to feed (call) the model at least once before training to have model.trainable_variables contain keras layers weights

Answer (score 5):

Let me start by having a simple model as an example to make it easier to explain and understand.

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

When using gradient tape you pass `model.trainable_weights` which returns the weights and biases of the entire model and use the optimizer to apply the gradients.

If you print the output of `model.trainable_weights`, you will get this output. **I removed the actual weights and biases for readability.**

```py
[<tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([...], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv2d/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([...], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([...], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([...], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(169, 10) dtype=float32, numpy=array([...], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([...], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(10, 10) dtype=float32, numpy=array([...], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([...], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'dense_2/kernel:0' shape=(10, 3) dtype=float32, numpy=array([...], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'dense_2/bias:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([...], dtype=float32)>]
```

As you can see each layer's kernel and bias was outputted as a list. This is the same output you pass to the gradient tape. If you want to pass just a specific layer, you can slice the list and get the desired weights you want to train.

```py
model.trainable_weights[0:2] # Get the first conv layer weights at index 0 and bias at index 1.
```

Which will output only the first conv layer weights and biases.

```py
[<tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([...], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'conv2d/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([...], dtype=float32)>]
```

Comment: What if I do not use the tf.keras.Sequential() API? What if I build my model by creating the layers one by one and having a reference to them which I can use later? Is this something you are not even supposed to do?

Comment: Do you mean using keras functional api or low level tensorflow ?

Comment: I am using tf.keras.layers for defining my network layers, just without the keras functional API. I just define them, but without putting them inside in any Sequential object or some other kind of wrapper. So I guess this can be considered low-level tensorflow?

Comment: This is considered a keras layer which shares the same properties like the predefined ones, so technically you can do the same thing.

Comment: If you can provid an example that would be great.

Comment: I added part of my code. Tried to include all the relevant parts. Hope it helps.