# model.trainable_variables return none

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I want to write my custom training function, but I couldn't access my trainable_weights because it returns []. I can get the weights using layer.get_weight() but my trainable_variables are empty. this is my training method:

```
def train_on_batch(X, y_real,model):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  tape.watch(X)
  y_pred = model(X, training= True)
  print(model.trainable_variables)
  loss_value = loss(y_real, y_pred)
grads = tape. gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
return loss_value
```

and this is my part of CNN model:

```
model_list = list()
# base model input
in_image = Input(shape=input_shape)
# conv 1x1
d = Conv2D(128, (1,1), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init, kernel_constraint= const)(in_image)
d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
# conv 3x3 (output block)
d = MinibatchStdev()(d)
d = Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init, kernel_constraint= const)(d)
d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
# conv 4x4
d = Conv2D(128, (4,4), padding='same', kernel_initializer=init, kernel_constraint= const)(d)
d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
# dense output layer
d = Flatten()(d)
out_class = Dense(1, name='dense')(d)
print(type(out_class))
# define model
model = Model(in_image, out_class)
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the last block of code of question. This code has given the best way to get the variables.

[TensorFlow 2.0 How to get trainable variables from tf.keras.layers layers, like Conv2D or Dense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59268822/tensorflow-2-0-how-to-get-trainable-variables-from-tf-keras-layers-layers-like)